# 2010 - How to set up home page with parameters

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I have website which is basically a "container" for subsites, and I would like to set it's homepage to "All site content" page (`viewlsts.aspx`) which is easy, but it should be filtered down to "Sites and Workspaces" section

So, is there any way to set up home page for website to address like:

```
.../_layouts/viewlsts.aspx?ShowSites=1
```

I am looking for solution without features, powershell and so on, because I am not farm admin, only site collection admin

UPDATE 1 - I came up with idea that i can embed iframe on homepage... it looks promising but I have duplicated top navigation, ribbon, etc... I deleted most of the top elements, but some of them are obligatory... I know it is kind of lame doing it this way, so I'll try to solve it with something more "pro" :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use SharePoint designer on your site, there is a solution for this. You can hide the lists/libraries from designer and make only sites appear in the All site content page. Though [this](http://www.codeasite.com/index.php/blog/item/12-hiding-sharepoint-libraries-lists-from-site-contents-and-tree-view) link demonstrates how to do it for SharePoint 2013, you can use it for SharePoint 2010 too, refer [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c1434fd3-d4cb-4ffc-882f-85f3c7f2b2c2/hide-list-from-all-site-content-page-of-sharepoint-site).

Comment: Yes, i use this now but tree view is narrow, shows only first 15 subsites (for rest of them You need to scroll down) and lacks descriptions of subsites...

Comment: First comment is uncomplete - 

I know how to hide lists, but - suprise suprise - you cannot set homepage for `_layouts/viewlsts.aspx` :). 

I use tree view now, but it is: 
- too narrow 
- shows about first 15 subsites (for rest of them You need to scroll down) 
- lacks descriptions of subsites

So I've tried to do this in iframe (see my question update 1) but it lacks "proffesional" look :)